# Unable to run SonarLint analysis on the whole project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarlint

I just updated my SonarLint plugin to v3.2.1 in the latest version of IntelliJ Idea (Community Version 2018.1.1) and the tab where I could choose the analysis' scope has gone so now I can't perform an analysis on the whole project at once only file by file.

I checked the SonerLint's release notes but it wasn't helpful at all.

Anyone faced this problem too? Or can anyone has any idea for it what happened?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I found it out...

The tab what I missed, now called `Report` and you can perform a `VCS changed files` analysis and `All project files` analysis with the two side buttons above the `STOP` icon/button.

[image]

I'd be grateful if this kind of changes will be shown in release notes...